# Vuetify non scrolling navigation drawer

Tags: css, vue.js, scroll, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have the next structure:
In navigation drawer:
 - Tooolbar
 - Search block
 - Items list
 - Footer

It looks so:[image]

The problem is, when i overflow items list, the scrolling is active for all navigation drawer instead of activate the items list scrolling.

I'am trying to make items list scrollable and without fixing it height (filling remain space till footer).
I have tried set height: 100vh for navigation drawer, but it didn't help.

JsFiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vxdbs65u/13/)

```js
Vue.use(Vuetify);

var vm = new Vue({
 el: "#app",
  data: {
   drawer: null
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons' rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <!-- Navigation drawer -->
    <!-- It shouldn't be scrollable -->
    <v-navigation-drawer width="380" dark app right v-model="drawer" permanent fixed>
      <!-- Toolbar -->
      <v-toolbar light color="blue" >
        <v-toolbar-side-icon/>
        <v-toolbar-title>Some</v-toolbar-title>
      </v-toolbar>
      
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <v-container grid-list-md >
      <v-layout row wrap >

        <v-flex d-flex xs12 order-xs5>
          <v-layout row wrap>

            <!-- Inputs -->
            <v-flex d-flex>
              <v-layout column wrap>

                <v-flex d-flex>
                      <v-text-field flat solo-inverted hide-details label="Search"/>
                </v-flex>
                
              
              </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
            
            <!-- Icons -->
            <v-flex d-flex xs1>
              <v-layout column wrap>
                   <v-flex d-flex>
                      <v-icon >search</v-icon>
                  </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        
        </v-flex>

        </v-layout>
      
      <v-layout column>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-flex>
          <hr>
        </v-flex>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      </v-layout>


    <!-- List items generator -->
    <!-- It should be scrollable -->
    <v-layout d-flex wrap align-space-around justify-center column fill-height style="overflow: auto">

        <v-flex v-for="i in 50" :key="`1${i}`">
          <v-card dark color="green">
            <v-card-text class="px-0">1</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>


    </v-layout>
    </v-container>

    
    <v-footer height="auto" color="primary lighten-1">
    <v-layout justify-center row wrap>
      <v-flex primary lighten-2 py-3 text-xs-center white--text xs12>
        &copy;2018 — <strong>Vuetify</strong>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-footer>
      
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-content>
      Some content
    </v-content>

  </v-app>
  </div>
 
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script>

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the `v-layout` of items to be like below:

```
<v-layout d-flex align-space-around justify-center column class="items">
```

And add this css:

```
.items {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: But OP doesn't want fixed height. So perhaps use `height: calc(100vh - OtherComponentsInNavbar);` to fill remaining height e.g. `height: calc(100vh - 56px -60px);`. I'm not sure if what would work cross-browers? But anyway, it seems to me that OP doesn't know what he's doing (I might be wrong tho) in the first place, so good luck to you.

Comment: Actually there is not a fixed height but a max-height.So this can work. However he maybe is not fully clear on what he is looking for. Or maybe i am not  understanding well. If he wants 3 rows, and want the second one to take the available height he can use CSS grid. `grid-template-rows`: 200px 1fr 100px`. Fixed with one line.

Comment: Oh, haha. You are right about `max-height` vs `height` but essentially same thing, it doesn't fill the remaining space, and I got the impression that it's what the OP wanted. Agree, there are various solutions for this probably. Question is too broad IMO to bother with answering it, and similar but narrowed question was probably answered somewhere in [tag:css] area.