# VuetifyJS - Scrolling v-navigation-drawer

Tags: vue.js, scroll, vuetify.js, drawer

I am new to VueJs and I started working on my first project which requires me to have a side panel (drawer) to serve as a navigation bar and it will always be visible.

So far so good it is done and it looks exactly as I wanted it.

The problem is that each time I put a lot of links the drawer doesn’t scroll in order to see all the links I have put there.

I have tried with css but nothing happens. Does anyone have any hint on what I should do?

I just need the drawer to be scrollable when links exceed the page or when the screen it’s small.

What I did is that I enclosed my drawer in a div with a class"scrollable" and added the below css:

```
.scrollable{ height:100%; overflow:auto;}
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384666/vuetify-non-scrolling-navigation-drawer) as it was the closest thing I could find to my problem

Comment: Can you show us this CSS?

Comment: @jom edited the question, please check

Comment: Did you solve this any other way?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue because of the 'absolute' keyword in the v-navigation-drawer. Try removing it and it might work.

`<v-navigation-drawer class="blue-grey lighten-5 height-app" v-model="drawer" temporary app width="310"> </v-navigation-drawer>`

Answer (score 1):

Navigation drawers should be scrollable if you add the `app` option as per [the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#api)

I still had the problem once where I could not add the `app` option to the drawer since I had two drawers side by side.

I just added this style to my drawer and it did the trick :

```
calc(100% - 48px); height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that i did not put the `app` attribute on th v-navigation-drawer

I just change:`<v-navigation-drawer  absolute temporary ></v-navigation-drawer>`

For:
`<v-navigation-drawer  absolute temporary app ></v-navigation-drawer>`

The adittion of `app` allow scrolling on my `v-navigation-drawer`

Answer (score 0):

Just add **app** attribute to  v-navigation-drawer tag

```
<v-navigation-drawer
 temporary
 app
 width="280"
 height="100vh"
>
```